# My iPhone screen doesn't turn off during calls?

Tags: hardware, screen, iphone, call

I have been recently noticing that my iphone does not turn off the screen when I answer calls or have it in my pocket... something seems off with proximity sensor... but how do I assure that this is the case, and not a software issue...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to test yourself whether or not it’s the case is to simply remove the case. Then use the phone and check whether or not you still have the same issue.

- If you still have the issue then you know it’s not the case.
- If you no longer have the issue then you know it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Call AppleCare and have us check out the iPhone by running a few quick diagnostics tests to it.

Comment: Applecare expired a while a go... what kind of tests are you suggesting?

Comment: Diagnostic tests such as software resource testing which tests the sensors in the iPhone. You don't need Applecare for them to do that.